# Popover Viewcontroller on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I think this is what it would be called. For an example, I'm talking about something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8gXo.png). Don't mind the actual content, I didn't have time to edit it. Does anyone know how to go about doing this or something very similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover

It's a popover view with the same API as the iPad version, but for iPhone